# How to generate Wireshark/tcpdump traces

Tags: python, wireshark, tcpdump, cap

I want to generate Wireshark/tcpdump traces at the end of a Python script, in a cap file.I looked at libcap for example but when executing the command, the script is stopped.
How can I generate a cap file without suspending my intial python script? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start command in background:

```
import os
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, 'your_command')
```

Or:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['your_command', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
```